# Problem getting CSRF_NONCE value (HTTP 400)

Tags: java, api, rest

I am trying to get CSRF_NONCE value, using java api, from my Windchill 12.1 server. But what ever I do I get HTTP code 400.

Tried queries were:
https://myServer/Windchill//servlet/rest/objects?$select=number&typeId=wt.part.WTPart
https://myServer/Windchill/servlet/odata/v3/PTC/GetCSRFToken()

Both queries works fine through Firefox browser. But, not using java code.

Does anybody have idea why one query works and the other not.

Thanks

I tried the following code:

```
URL url = new URL ("https://myServer/Windchill/servlet/odata/v3/PTC/GetCSRFToken()");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authString); //authstring is Base64 encoded
conn.connect();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
conn.disconnect();
//---------------
```

I also tried different url for example:
"https://myServer/Windchill//servlet/rest/objects?$select=number&typeId=wt.part.WTPart"
and i get right data using the same code as above.

Comment: is `()` valid in the url?

Comment: Yes, it is set by PTC.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was missing the following statement:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

After that everything works fine.

Best regards!